# Nouns for calling something we don't know how to call it

Tags: word-request, nouns

My daughter always calls things she does not know how are they called as ***thingy***. She could say just ***that thing*** but she wants to express that she doesn't know how are they called and sometimes she just wants to make it sound funny.

Is this expression used in English and are there any other words for calling things we don't know how are they called while expressing that we don't know how are they called to the listeners?

Comment: *something?* Say - *I don't know but there was *something; Something happened to her and she fainted; There was a cute little something!* and so on...? Perhaps?

Comment: Something sounds a bit not so exciting. Her word thingy is more like the **whozits** and **whatzits** from the Disney song; Part of Your World.

Comment: This is likely to be counted as too broad.  There are dozens of words, often dialectal - Oojahs, Hoojits, Doofers, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, from my previous comment, I meant ***thingamabobs***.

Comment: **Thingamabobs**? I got twenty, but don't really need any more. Now... **whatchamacallits**, **doodads**, **widgets**, **thingamajigs**... I can always use more. (Yeah... there are plenty of nonsense words in English that are used when you can't put your finger on the right word.)

Comment: @T.J.L. It's that **whojamaflip**...the **wossname**, you know?

Comment: Possible answers can be found here: [How might a native speaker refer to an object when they can't recall its real name?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/418/how-might-a-native-speaker-refer-to-an-object-when-they-cant-recall-its-real-na) and here: [http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34648/what-do-americans-call-something-when-they-cannot-remember-its-name-temporarily](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34648/what-do-americans-call-something-when-they-cannot-remember-its-name-temporarily)

Comment: From my collection: business gizmo matter mess shebang stuff thing thingummy things thingy. - Oald has thingy, so it's not a made up word but a dictionary entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "thingy" is widely used in English- to talk about things you don't know the name of, have forgotten, or don't want to mention- for example genitals.

Yes, there are lots of similar words- some of them widely known, some regional, and others made up on the spur of the moment, as your daughter probably did.

Answer (score 1):

I would second Maulik with 'something', and one more noun meaning 'something' is - ***stuff***.

I've just came across an article on [Vague expressions](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/vague-expressions), which is pretty well-structured and rather interesting.

Comment: I don't think either *something* or *stuff* would normally work in the contexts OP seems to be asking about. Say you're at the dinner table, can't reach the condiment set, and don't know/can't recall the word [cruet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruet). You'd never say *Pass me the **something*** - only *...the **thingy***. If you said *Pass me the **stuff*** that wouldn't really match OP's context, because that's a "collective" noun usage (for which *my* vernacular term would be *Pass me the **gubbins***).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "thingy" is a thing.

There is actually a long list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:thingy). Also, it redirects to different pages talking about [placeholder names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name) and [terms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_placeholder_terms). Depending on what you forgot, you need a different word. For example, if you forgot the name of somebody see [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:whatshisname).